# accessing data from hash within an array

Tags: ruby

So I have some number of hashes within an array like follows

```
arr=[
      {a: 1, b:2, c:3},
      {a:3, b:5, c:4},
      {a:6 b:7, c:9}
     ]
```

I want to derive the sum of numbers from the last hash.
I was thinking of something like

```
  arr.last[each_value.inject(:+)]
```

it doesn't work however, what is a better way of doing this?

Comment: What does, "It doesn't work" mean? Your first exception would have been `SyntaxError` from the line containing `{a:6 b:7, c:9}`. If you simply transcribed that incorrectly (which you wouldn't have done if you had tested that `arr` was valid before posting), your last line raises the exception `NameError (undefined local variable or method 'each_value' for main:Object)`. That is essential information you need to report in your question; indeed, it pinpoints the error, as error messages often do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code

```rb
arr.last[each_value.inject(:+)] # doesn't work
```

`arr.last` is a hash. so you can use [Hash#each_value](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0.preview1/Hash.html#method-i-each_value)

```rb
arr.last.each_value.inject(:+) #=> 22
```

Other ways [Hash#values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0.preview1/Hash.html#method-i-values), [Enumerable#sum](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0.preview1/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum), [Enumerable#reduce](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0.preview1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce)

```rb
arr.last.values.sum #=> 22
arr.last.sum { |_key, val| val } #=> 22 
arr.last.reduce(0) { |sum, (_key, val)| sum + val } #=> 22
```